# How to apply Keras Normalization to a ParallelMapDataset without making it eager?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a Tensorflow Keras CNN over images, too much training data to fit into memory.  I've got a tf.Dataset preprocessing pipeline that reads the images from HDF5 files using a `dataset.map()` pipeline step.  Now I'm trying to normalize the numeric image data to 0 mean and unit variance.

I'm following [this example from this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#normalizing_numerical_features), except that I have that `.map()` in there:

```py
def load_features_from_hdf5(filename):
    spec = tf.TensorSpec(feature_shape, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)
    dataset = tfio.IODataset.from_hdf5(filename, "/features", spec=spec)  # returns a Dataset
    feature = dataset.get_single_element()
    feature.set_shape(feature_shape)
    return feature

train_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames).map(load_features_from_fbank, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=None)
normalizer.adapt(train_x.take(1000))

train_x_normalized = normalizer(train_x)  #  <-- ValueError
```

`adapt()` successfully computes the mean and variance from the dataset.  But when I try to actually apply normalization of values on the exact same dataset, it errors while trying to convert my ParallelMapDataset to an EagerTensor.

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<ParallelMapDataset shapes: (41, 682, 1), types: tf.float32>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.ParallelMapDataset'>) to a Tensor.

How can I get this working?  Since the data is so large, I wouldn't think I want to make anything eager until training starts.  Should I make the normalization an explicit pipeline step on the Dataset?  Or an explicit layer on the model itself?  (If the latter case, how can I bring the mean and variance values from training time to inference time in another process?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create dummy data
train_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((100, 28, 28, 3)), tf.random.normal((100, 1)))).batch(10)

normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=None)

# Adapt
normalizer.adapt(train_x.map(lambda x, y: x))

# Apply to images
train_x_normalized = train_x.map(lambda x, y: (normalizer(x), y))
```

Example:

```py
for x, y in train_x_normalized.take(1):
  print(tf.reduce_mean(x), tf.math.reduce_variance(x))
```

```
tf.Tensor(0.00930768, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(1.0023469, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Or, as you mentioned in your question, your can use the normalization layer as part of your model.

Comment: Mapping the normalizer over the dataset works, per your example. (Note that it only works if the dataset knows its own shape, which I find to be a hit-or-miss proposition sometimes dealing with tfio.IODataset, but that's a different question!)